# Mapping into Hurewicz cofibrations.

Tags: homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

In Strøm's paper "The Homotopy Category is a Homotopy Category" he proves
(Lemma 4)  that if $Y$ is compact and if $i:A\to X$  is a cofibration, then the induced map
$$
i_*:  A^Y \to X^Y
$$
is also a cofibration.

The proof goes like this:  he's already shown that $i:A\to X$ is a cofibration if and only
if there is a function $u: X\to I$ such that $A = u^{-1}(0)$ and a deformation
$H:X\times I \to X$ of $X$ that is constant on $A$ and pushes $U = u^{-1}([0,1))$
into $A$.  Then he defines
$$
v(\alpha) = \sup \{ i\circ \alpha(Y) \}
\qquad \mathrm{and}\qquad K (\alpha, t) (y) = H(\alpha(y), t).
$$
This shows that $i_*$ is a cofibration since $v^{-1}(0) = A^Y$ and $K$ deforms
$V = v^{-1}([0,1))$ into $A^Y$.
When I try to prove that $v$ is continuous, it's very helpful to have the compactness of $Y$.

My question is:  can the  compactness hypothesis be dropped, 
 perhaps if we work with compactly generated spaces?

EDIT:  Ok, I see the problem with noncompact domains.
The space $I^{\mathbb{R}}$ is a good example.  Functions in the set $\mathcal{U}(C,V)$
($C\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ compact, $V\subseteq I$ open) are only limited on $C$, and so can take
very large values elsewhere.    You can cut this down a bit by taking intersections, and this does the job for compact domains, but you can only take finitely many.  These spaces
being as nice as can be, this is a dead question.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I got rid of the empty set in the name of Arne Strøm.


Comment: I know that $\varnothing$ was originally ø, but they are rendered in different fonts and so are not interchangeable.  I apologise if it was meant as a witticism, but it looked horrendous.

Comment: (José - simultaneous edits there, I think.)

Comment: @all:  No, I just didn't know how to make an ø  (still don't, that's cut-and-paste).

Comment: Jeff: you can use HTML entities in questions and answers, so &oslash; will work.  (It doesn't work in comments for some bizarre reason though - I had to go to José's user page to find an e-acute to use!)

Comment: I can get ø from the Special Characters in the Edit menu of my Mac. It has a steeper diagonal line than most emptyset symbols.

Comment: But that's when I'm typing the comment. When the comment appears, the slope is less.